# Recyclerview onbindview don't work correct when Click on item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, onclick

I try to update the list item weight code work fine

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public viewlistx onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View xd = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lay_yesno_list,parent,false);

        return new viewlistx(xd);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  viewlistx holder, final int position) {


        btyesi = holder.btyes;


        holder.btyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.w("click","pos: " + position);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btyesi.getLayoutParams();
                params.weight = 2.0f;
                btyesi.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public class viewlistx extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        private final TextView btyes;

        public viewlistx(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            btyes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yesbtx);
        }
    }


}
```

but the problem is when I click an item it changes the next item weight

for example pos, 0 click pos 1 item value change or pos 1 clicked pos 2 item value change

What's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try  adding notifyItemChanged(position) below btyesi.setLayoutParams(params); this will refresh the view with new weight.

Comment: @PrinceAli i try it same behaviour

Comment: @PrinceAli there is nothing on adapter there only one textview in liner layout but i will send whole adapter code send it

Comment: @PrinceAli I send the whole adapter code can you now tell me where the is problem?

Comment: @PrinceAli ty for the response I found where is a problem is in onbindview holder just change it to final holder and its work fine

Answer (score 0):

found way to fix that for use value animation on list must change

```
holder
```

to

```
final holder
```

and its work fine